# Keeping a click button underneath a dev element after it is cereated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set an add button to add another div element onto the page when it is clicked. I am having a problem get the button to drop underneath the new div element after the div is created. The button stays in place and the new div is add underneath it when it is clicked, and if it is clicked again the button still stays in the same place and adds an additional div. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
            <fieldset id="college">
            <legend id="namefields"><h2>College, University or Professional School</h2></legend>
            <table width="834">
                <tr>
                    <td width="439" height="61">
                        Name of School <input  type="text"size="40" maxlength="50" name="college" id="college"/>
                    </td>
                    <td width="383"> 
                        Location <input type="text" name="location" size="40">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="834">
                <tr>
                    <td width="272" height="54">
                        Start Date <input type="date" name="date" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="273" height="54">
                        End Date <input type="date" name="date" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="273" height="54">
                        Credit Hours <input type="text" name="creditHrs" size="10"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="869">
                <tr>
                    <td width="439" height="61">
                        Course of Study <input  type="text"size="40" maxlength="50" name="college" id="college"/>
                    </td>
                    <td width="418"> 
                        <label for="degreeType" id="degreeType">Degree Earned (transcripts may be required)</label>
                            <select style="width: 310px;" id="degreeType" name="degreeType" tabindex="0">
                            <option value="select one">Select One</option>
                            <option value="associates">Associates</option>
                            <option value="bachelors">Bachelors</option>
                            <option value="certification">Certification</option>
                            <option value="masters">Masters</option>
                            <option value="doctorate">Doctorate</option>
                            <option value="inprogress"> In Progress</option>
                            <option value="0">Not Applicable</option>
                          </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>            
        </fieldset>
        <button id= "addSchool" onclick="addSchool()">Add another school</button>
            <script>

            var original = document.getElementById('college');

            function addSchool() 
            {
                var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
                original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
            }
            </script>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without jQuery you can use insertBefore like this

```
var original = document.getElementById('college');
var button = document.getElementById('addSchool');
function addSchool(){
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone,button);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zg2cE/

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will check it out as soon as possible.